# Auto select value in dropdown

Tags: angular, angular8, ngx-select-dropdown

How do I set a value as the default selected value in the dropdown? I am using angular 8.
I have the following html

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label class="form-control-label col-form-label-sm">Content Type</label>
        <select class="form-control form-control-sm" [(ngModel)]="item.contentType"  formControlName="contentType" name="contentType">
          <option   *ngFor="let contentType of contentTypes" [value]="contentType.name" >{{contentType.displayName}}</option>
        </select>
      </div>
```

I have tried using `[selected]="contentType.name=='TEXT'"` but the dropdown still does not show the default selected value as "Text Only".

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label class="form-control-label col-form-label-sm">Content Type</label>
        <select class="form-control form-control-sm" [(ngModel)]="item.contentType" formControlName="contentType" name="contentType">
          <option *ngFor="let contentType of contentTypes" [value]="contentType.name" [selected]="contentType.name=='TEXT'">{{contentType.displayName}}</option>
        </select>
      </div>
```

contentTypes is an array of `[{"name":"TEXT","displayName":"Text Only"},{"name":"AUDIO","displayName":"Audio"},{"name":"VIDEO","displayName":"Video"}]`

Comment: Can you set default value for item.contentType before you init select? Setting it to "TEXT" might preselect TEXT option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Karu,

by default item.contentType should being inited with value coresponding with some option from your list of contentTypes. If you init `item.contentType` with value `TEXT` for example, option with value `TEXT` will be preselected by default.

Or, you can just put `option` with `null` value with text `Select content` (for example). And validate it, if it should be required. Something like:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label class="form-control-label col-form-label-sm">Content Type</label>
   <select class="form-control form-control-sm" [(ngModel)]="item.contentType"
         name="contentType">
      <option [value]="null">Select content</option>
      <option *ngFor="let contentType of contentTypes" [value]="contentType.name"> 
          {{contentType.displayName}}
      </option>
    </select> 
</div>
```

Anyway, deside which approach for building form you will use ([Reactive forms or Template driven forms](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/difference-between-template-driven-and-reactive-forms-angular)). Because you did a mistake in definition for select component. Use only `[(ngModel)]` definition and remove `formControlName="contentType"`, if you would like to use template driven forms pattern. Study this first in link provided.

Answer (score 0):

I could make it work by this example

**template**

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label class="form-control-label col-form-label-sm">Content Type</label>
   <select class="form-control form-control-sm" formControlName="contentType" 
         name="contentType">
      <option *ngFor="let contentType of contentTypes" [value]="contentType.name"> 
          {{contentType.displayName}}
      </option>
    </select> 
</div>
```

**in ts**

```
// if you will give the value to the contentType control it will be selected item
// something like this 
export class ReleaseComponent implements OnInit {

   ngOnInit() {
      this.yourForm.get('contentType').patchValue('TEXT'); 
      // or
      this.yourForm.get('contentType').patchValue(this.contentTypes[0].name); 
   }
}
```

I hope this can be helpfull

Comment: It can help when Karu will rewrite approach to Reactive forms pattern. Karu uses Template Driven Form

Comment: he uses both and I have removed the `[ngModel]` from above example

Comment: Good hint Ashot, I saw only [(ngModel)] definition

Comment: Ashot if you have time, it would be great if you provide example with correct solution for reactive forms pattern. In your answer few things are missing, for example: [formGroup] definition in template and ts file and ofcourse definition for formGroup instance with contentType formControl

Answer (score 0):

Use [selected] in option 
like this. Your selected condition is wrong, i think

```
<select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="item.contentType">
   <option *ngFor="let contentType of contentTypes" [value]="contentType.name" [selected]="contentType.name==item.contentType">{{contentType.displayName}}</option>
</select>
```